# Image boundary detection using python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am newbie who is trying to learn opencv-python in Ubuntu - 14.04. I want to draw the boundary around the black layer at the center of the image that we tested in our laboratory. After finding the boundary i want to perform some action on the image inside boundary. Here is the image http://prntscr.com/5qfxha

But all the documents and materials in opencv are provided only for a specific set of images. There is no specific detail of how to deal with custom images. I read every single question and as I told I am newbie i am very confused so please guide me through this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by custom image ?

Comment: real time images( please check the link in my question ).

Comment: You mean the stone image ? If so I did and does not give me a clue (:

Comment: yaa and i need to find the boudnary of that black pattern at the center of that stone so i need some suggestion on how to proceed.

Comment: I've edited my answer, it fits more with your needs.

Answer (score 0):

`findContours` can do the trick, 
see [C++](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/09/find-contour.html)'s and [Python](http://opencvpython.blogspot.fr/2012/06/hi-this-article-is-tutorial-which-try.html) example/tutorial.

Once you have your contours, check
[`ConnectedComponent`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=connectedcomponents#connectedcomponents) to find who's included in who ? (only Opencv 3)

Comment: My bad, it's now updated. But remember that usually methods will have the same name either in Python or Cpp documentation.